# How to apply same function to mutiple elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to apply a single js function to the buttons on my webpage. Whenever I click on the first button the function runs as expected, however, when I click on the second or third button the function runs on the first button and not on the other two as intended. Help, please??

```js
function buttonOp() {
  var dots = document.getElementById('dots');
  var moreBtn= document.getElementsByClassName('moreButton');
  var moretext= document.getElementById('more');

  if(dots.style.display == 'none'){
    dots.style.display = 'inline';
    moreBtn.innerHTML = 'read more';
    moretext.style.display = 'none';
  }else {
    dots.style.display = 'none';
    moreBtn.innerHTML = 'show less';
    moretext.style.display = 'block';
  }
};
```

```html
<div>
            <p>Title: The Autobiography of Malcolm x <span id="dots">...</span> </p>
            <span id="more">
              <p>Author: Malcom x, Alex Haley</p>
              <p>Published: October 29, 1965</p>
              <p>Genres: Biography, Autobiography</p>
            </span>
            <button onclick="buttonOp()" class="moreButton">read more</button>
            <p><img alt="cover" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81kQBRCqt-L.jpg"></p>
          </div>

          <div>
            <p>Title: I Know Why The Caged Bird Sings <span id="dots">...</span></p>
            <span id="more">
              <p>Author: Maya Angelou</p>
              <p>Published: 1969</p>
              <p>Genres: Biography, Autobiography</p>
            </span>
            <button onclick="buttonOp()" class="moreButton">read more</button>
            <p><img alt="cover" src='https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71IrTqSVOjL.jpg'></p>
          </div>

          <div>
            <p>Title: The Worlds Fastest Man: The Extraordinary Life of Cyclist Major Taylor, Americas First Black Sports Hero <span id="dots">...</span></p>
            <span id="more">
              <p>Author: Michael Kranish</p>
              <p>Published: May 7, 2019</p>
              <p>Genres: Biography</p>
            </span>
            <button onclick="buttonOp()" class="moreButton">read more</button>
            <p><img alt="cover" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81V1whsTaYL.jpg"></p>
          </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: ID must be unique on HTML. You are repeating id like id="more"

Answer (score 0):

Your button clicks are working on each button.
The problem here is, in HTML one "id" can only be used with one element, but you have 3 elements having the same id.

Here is a simple (but inconvenient?) way to solve your issue.

```
<div>
            <p>Title: The Autobiography of Malcolm x <span id="dots1">...</span> </p>
            <span id="more1">
              <p>Author: Malcom x, Alex Haley</p>
              <p>Published: October 29, 1965</p>
              <p>Genres: Biography, Autobiography</p>
            </span>
            <button onclick="buttonOp(1)" class="moreButton1">read more</button>
            <p><img alt="cover" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81kQBRCqt-L.jpg"></p>
          </div>

          <div>
            <p>Title: I Know Why The Caged Bird Sings <span id="dots2">...</span></p>
            <span id="more2">
              <p>Author: Maya Angelou</p>
              <p>Published: 1969</p>
              <p>Genres: Biography, Autobiography</p>
            </span>
            <button onclick="buttonOp(2)" class="moreButton2">read more</button>
            <p><img alt="cover" src='https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71IrTqSVOjL.jpg'></p>
          </div>

          <div>
            <p>Title: The Worlds Fastest Man: The Extraordinary Life of Cyclist Major Taylor, Americas First Black Sports Hero <span id="dots3">...</span></p>
            <span id="more3">
              <p>Author: Michael Kranish</p>
              <p>Published: May 7, 2019</p>
              <p>Genres: Biography</p>
            </span>
            <button onclick="buttonOp(3)" class="moreButton3">read more</button>
            <p><img alt="cover" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81V1whsTaYL.jpg"></p>
          </div>

        </div>
```

```
function buttonOp(id) {
  console.log("Clicked"+id)
  var dots = document.getElementById('dots'+id);
  var moreBtn= document.getElementsByClassName('moreButton'+id);
  var moretext= document.getElementById('more'+id);

  if(dots.style.display == 'none'){
    dots.style.display = 'inline';
    moreBtn.innerHTML = 'read more';
    moretext.style.display = 'none';
  }else {
    dots.style.display = 'none';
    moreBtn.innerHTML = 'show less';
    moretext.style.display = 'block';
  }
};
```